# Find matching Predicate. Predicate of Predicate?

Tags: java, guava

I have a collection of `Predicates`, say `List<Predicate<File>>`. I then have a single `File` and I need to get the predicate (if any) that matches the file. I was thinking along the lines of using `Iterables.find()` but of course that takes a `Predicate` not a value to pass into a `Predicate`. I thought about implementing the following but don't know if there already exists a mechanism.

```
public static <T> Predicate<Predicate<? super T>> createInversePredicate(
        final T value) {
    return new Predicate<Predicate<? super T>>() {

        @Override
        public boolean apply(Predicate<? super T> input) {
            return input.apply(value);
        }
    };
}
```

This would allow me to do the following:

```
private List<Predicate<File>> filters = ...;

@Nullable
Predicate<File> findMatching(File file){
    return Iterables.find(filters, createInversePredicate(file), null);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guava team member here.

This is how I'd do it.  There isn't a better way.

Comment: It there already a utility method like "createInversePredicate"? If not, should I suggest it as an issue?

Comment: You could, but it doesn't seem like a very common use case.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid the complexity of creating an "inverse" predicate, and simply use imperative code:

```
private List<Predicate<File>> filters = ...;

@Nullable
Predicate<File> findMatchingFilter(File file){
    for (Predicate<File> filter : filters) {
        if (filter.apply(file)) {
            return filter;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It's more straightforward, and the next programmer won't need to take 1 minute to understand this "inverse" predicate business :)

Comment: I disagree for two reasons: 1) I hate repeated code and this includes redoing what exists in a library. It is a area where a bug can slip in. 2) There are a lot of methods in Guava where I could use this without having to add code (filter, find, findOnly, etc)

Comment: I'm not saying that such an inverse predicate is always a bad idea (which is why I upvoted your question yesterday). It makes sense if you find yourself reusing such a predicate multiple times and/or in different ways (filter, find, findOnly, etc.). But, until then, I'd follow the YAGNI principle, and strive for simplicity. The functional idioms caveats section in the Guava wiki is also relevant: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 users can do this:

```
Predicate<File> findMatching(File file) {
  List<Predicate<File>> matchingFilters = filters.stream().filter(predicate -> predicate.test(file)).collect(Collectors.toList());
  return matchingFilters.isEmpty()? null : matchingFilters.get(0);
}
```

Here I am assuming only one predicate will match the file.

You can also use `Optional<Predicate<File>>` instead of `@Nullable` in Java 8.